# Flyway placeholder when exist value if not exit it will skip replaceholder

Tags: java, flyway

I would like to replaceholder only value that exist if not exist I want skip it.

Example:

1 V1__customer.sql

```
insert into customer(id,name) values(1, ${name});
```

2 V2__staff.sql

```
insert into staff(id,age) values(1, ${age});
```

in code

```
            ThreadLocalContextUtil.setInstance(instance);
            final var flyway = new Flyway();
            flyway.setDataSource(Datasource.class);
            flyway.setLocations("instance_db");
            flyway.setOutOfOrder(true);
            flyway.setValidateOnMigrate(false);
            flyway.getPlaceholders().put("name", "mr empty");
            applyProperties(flyway);
            flyway.migrate();
```

**Question :How to replace on name only and for age skip it.**

Answer (score 1):

This use case isn't really supported. Flyway will produce an error if it finds a placeholder token without a corresponding value. I can think of a workaround however.

You could 'seed' your placeholders with empty strings. This will stop Flyway producing an error for unset values.

Inside your migration scripts you could then introduce guard conditions that only run when values are provided.

For instance, in Java:

```
// Seed with empty strings
flyway.getPlaceholders().put("name", "");
flyway.getPlaceholders().put("id", "");
...
// Overwrite some of the placeholders
flyway.getPlaceholders().put("name", "mr empty");
```

Then in your script (pseudo code):

```
IF '${name}' NOT EQUAL TO '' THEN
insert into customer(id,name) values(1, ${name});
```

If you want built in support you should [create an issue on Flyway's GitHub page](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues).

Comment: I got your idea but some of that relate to my logic code I need replace it by by runtime.

Comment: do you have any solution more ?

Comment: It's not a supported feature of Flyway. Create an issue on the GitHub page requesting it: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues. This'll put it on our radar, and allow other people to help with workarounds.